# Can't qplot data in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot this but I think It's due to some NA error i can't plot it? Does someone know how I could fix it?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(readxl)
library(gridExtra)
Marama <- read_excel('MaramaBeanOilOx.xlsx')
Marama.oil <- subset(Marama, Product=='oil')
qplot(data=Marama.oil,
      + Temperature:Light, sqrt(PV),
      + geom=c('boxplot','jitter'))+
  + facet_grid(.~Month)+theme_bw()
```

I get the following error msg:

```
    Error: unexpected '=' in:
"      + Temperature:Light, sqrt(PV),
      + geom="
```

Here's the data for Marama:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMaNI.png)

When I'm trying to subset Marama.oil i get following msg:
"No data available in the table"

Comment: Try remove the `+` sign in your `qplot()`?

Comment: When I remove the plus sign i get this error instead

"Error in Temperature:Light : argument of length 0"

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. The error is describing "The way your code is written is incorrect". Eg: one or the other column in `Temperature:Light` does not exist in `Marama.oil`.

Comment: Thanks - When I'm trying to create the Marama.oil it says that "No data available in the table". Is that due to the Na boxes in the data for Marama? And do you maybe know a way I can fix this isssue? Thanks for the help by the way